# Google Calender API - Create/Edit Event Times Not Accurate

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, google-calendar-api

We are trying to create events in our Google Calendar using .Net/C#. When we create the events they are always 5hrs behind the time scheduled (ex. event from 12:00 PM-11:59 PM becomes 7:00am – 6:59pm).

Below is how we are creating the event:

```
//creating new event object based off of the Google API Event type
            Event newEvent = new Event() {
                //assigning values for events
                Summary = (@event.bandName + " " + @event.eventStart.ToShortTimeString() + "-" + @event.eventEnd.ToShortTimeString() + " $" + @event.ticketPrice).ToUpper(),
                Description = bandLink + " " + @event.description,
                Start = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = @event.eventStart
                },
                End = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = @event.eventEnd
                },
                
            };
```

We have tried doing something like:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(@event.eventStart, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

and then assigning this value to the Start Time

```
Start = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = start
                },
```

but we still get the original issue (event from 12:00 PM-11:59 PM becomes 7:00am – 6:59pm).

Our Summary displays with the proper time in the google calendar, it is only the Start/End times of the event that are displaying wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert):

> start.dateTime

> The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC3339). **A time zone offset is required** unless a time zone is explicitly specified in timeZone.

This means that you need to either

- explicitly set the `timeZone` property or
- incorporate the time zone offset into `dateTime`

Sample:

```cs
Start = new EventDateTime()
 {
   DateTime = new DateTime(2021, 12, 01, 11, 11, 0),
   TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles",
 }
```